# Webi 4.x publication

Tags: business-objects, sapb1

I am working on BO 4.1. There is a webi report that has list of students, courses and instructors grouped by programs. The report needs to be published to the program directors. Since each program has one primary director I have made a publication that list program director IDs, programs name and program directors email address. There are two queries; one that pull student, program and course 
information and the other pulls course and instructor information. These queries linked my courses as merged dimension.  The webi report shows all the necessary data.
When I publish this report it publishes to the correct program directors (mapped by program), but after the report block ends, there is a second block with list of instructor that are not part of that particular program.

The instructor names are detailed objects.  There is prompt for program to select one or more programs.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the following information: the version of BusinessObjects you're running, the error message you're encountering, how your publication is configured (are you sure it's a publication and not just a schedule?). What do you mean with *multiple queries*: data providers? And detail objects? If you want accurate answers, details matter. Screenshots are always a welcome addition too.

Comment: I apologize for not being specific.  I am working on BO 4.1.  There is a webi report that has list of student, and instructors  grouped by programs.  The report needs to be published to the program directors.  Since each program has one primary director I have made a publication that list program director IDs, programs name and program directors.  There are two queries; one that pull student, program and course info and second that pulls course and the instructor.  Course object is a merged dimension and the final report had instructor names a detail objects.

Comment: Please edit your original question and put the additional information in there so others can see it immediately instead of having to read through the comments. Also, you can't add screenshots to comments.

Comment: When I publish this report it publishes the to the correct program directors (mapped by program), but after the report block ends, there is a second block with list of instructor that are not part of that particular program.

Comment: The instructors that aren't part of any program are listed separately. As the Program ID would be `NULL`, how would it know where to send this information? What is it you'd like to do with this block of information?

Comment: I would like to not show up the instructor where Program ID is null in the published report to the individual recipients.    So each program director views only the students, course, programs and instructor that are part of their program.

Comment: I change the instructor field in the report to only show value when the program field is not null.  Now it published the correct data except there are empty fields where the instructor names use to be.  So each recipient is getting their report with some blank rows.  How so I correct that?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also tried to insert a section on Program ID and then checked "Hide when empty" on the section block and even tried Hide when formula "IsNull([Program ID])" in the report format section.  Still the report shows those empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kristof mentioned my report was pulling instructor where program ID was NULL.  Once I specified my instructor FOREACH course section, it resolved the issue.